# How can I set the not null field? Spring boot, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm new as java programmer. I am writing a simple app with spring boot and hibernate.

I have problem with not null field. How can I set them, because when I write:

```
@NotNull
private String foo;
```

I see in database (postgres) I can insert null value but I expected that I can't.

Also when I write:

```
private int number;
```

I expected the `number` can be null but I was wrong.

So how can I set nullable and not nullable values on `string, int, double`?

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: which `@NotNull` annotation have you imported? `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` or from jetbrains or ... Have you generated the tables via hibernate or manually?

Comment: *I expected the number can be null but I was wrong.* No `int` is a pimitive type which cannot be null use `Integer` instead

Comment: @Jens I use `com.sun.istack.NotNull;`. I also found that when I write: `@Column private int number;` (because `@Column` has default nullable set on true.) I can insert null value but I not sure is good practice.

Comment: Do you want Bean Validation to trigger when you persist the entity? If so, use `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`. If not, just use `@Column(nullable = false)`. Hibernate does not understand what `com.sun.istack.NotNull` is

Comment: As a side note, if you use `int`, and make the column nullable when creating the DB schema yourself, Hibernate *will* allow such a thing. You'll just get a NPE whenever Hibernate actually *finds* a `NULL` in the column when trying to map it onto the entity. So, it probably doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add @Entity tag beginning of your model and you can use @Notnull tag where you want such as:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotNull
private BigDecimal price;
```

}

fore more information you can take a look that [link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-notnull-vs-nullable)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add below dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then you can @Notnull from javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

```
@NotNull
private String foo;
```

or you can use @Column annotation from Java persistent API as below.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private String foo;
```